# Не пойму как передать зависимости dagger в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, dagger2

Сейчас я опубликую код, который работает с Activity.

```
open class App : Application(){

        open lateinit var component: ApplicationComponent

        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            createDaggerComponentGraph()

        }

        open fun getAppComponent():ApplicationComponent{
            return component
        }

        open fun createDaggerComponentGraph(){
            component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                    .build()
        }

    }
```

2.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ApplicationModule::class,
        ArticlesBindingModule::class
))

open interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(target: MainActivity)
    fun inject(fragment: ArticlesFragment)
    fun inject(target: App)

}
```

3.

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(val context: Context){

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesContext():Context{
        return context
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getFragmentA(): ArticlesFragment = ArticlesFragment()
}
```

4. Подключаю к Activity

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
   @Inject lateinit var mFragmentArticles : ArticlesFragment

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       (application as? App)?.component?.inject(this)
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   } }
   ```

Но я аналогичный способом в `Fragment` как в `MainActvity` не могу сделать. Dagger выбрасывает ошибки. Ниже будет код из класса который зависим от Fragment.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

Вызывает ошибку `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector was found for info.android_developer_community.androiddevelopercommunity.ui.articles.ArticlesFragment`

Пробовал так, и не только в этом методе

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    (activity as App).component.inject(this)
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

Ошибка `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: info.android_developer_community.androiddevelopercommunity.ui.MainActivity cannot be cast to info.android_developer_community.androiddevelopercommunity.App`

Comment: Очень сложно дать совет по тому коду который есть. Android имеет определенные особенности в спользовании DI- для этого Dagger2 использует методты INjector которые внутри создает компоненты и сабкомпоненты Dagger, для того чтобы подружить АРхитектуру Android с жизненными циклами уже его компонентов. В вашем случае это DI без Scope based on, те вы его используете, чтоб использовать. Вам нет необходимости делать что-то вроде  (application as? App)?.component?.inject(this) у вас экземпляр фрагмента создается при генерации AppModule вы можете инжектить его в другие классы и использовать.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei сейчас я добился работоспособность кода с помощью `(activity!!.application as? App)?.component?.inject(this)` я добавил `activity` перед `application`.